# How to convert HTML input type="file" to a octet-stream

Tags: ajax, azure, file, post

I am making a web application where a user selects an image using

```
<input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

I need to upload the selected image to Azure so that I can further process it. The Azure docs state that I must use a POST call with the Content-Type set as "application/octet-stream" and the body is to contain the image file.

I have the following:

```
const fileEl = document.getElementById('file');
fileEl.addEventListener( 'change', async (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  const response = await fetch( "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/abc/detect/iterations/Iteration0/url", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
        "Prediction-Key": "123",
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
     },
     body: file
  } );

  console.log( response.ok );
} );
```

The problem is that this is failing ... I'm guessing that **body: file** is incorrect.  How do I convert the file object to something that I'm supposed to send in the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

I have the wrong url in the fetch command, that is why nothing is working!  I fixed that and body: file works just fine